# How to take updates from Master into Branch in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, branch, tortoisegit

I have created a branch in Git repository 10 days before and worked on some changes in the created branch. Now I need to update my branch with master updates (ie commits done over the master after the branch taken) and need to merge with master.

help me how to achieve this in TortoiseGit.

Guide me with TortoiseGit not through Git bash or Git CLI etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11):

The command you are looking for is "merge".

With merge you can integrate the changes of another branch into your active branch, e.g. integrate the changes of your Branch into master.

Merging can be done using several ways:

1. Open the context menu in explorer, open the TortoiseGit submenu and select Merge.
2. Open the log dialog and right click on the commit/branch you want to merge and select merge.

In both cases the very same dialog opens. Here you can select/check the branch and set some more advanced options. Clicking Ok will start the merge.

Whenever you merge conflicts can occurr, e.g. the very same file is edited on both branches., which need to be [resolved manually](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-conflicts.html) and committed (the resulting merge commit includes your changes as well as the changes of the other branch).

Thats it.

See https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-merge.html.

Comment: I just did this and it gave a couple of files for conflict resolution, which I did. However, it just totally skipped over many big changes that were in main that I still don't have in my branch.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the branch folder and do a Pull from main. It will show files in conflict and let you resolve them in the process. This was the easiest way I found to do it.